# Check if response has error

Tags: json, bash, shell, response, jq

I have some web API, which response with JSON, and a shell script, which sends requests with curl and processing JSON with jq.

Response structure is the following:

- Error response: `{ "error": "error_message" }` - single struct.
- Good response: `[ { "element1": "value1", "element2": "value2", "element3": "value3" } ]` - array of structs of 3 elements (fixed amount).

The problem is that user may enter some data causing API response with the error. In this case, I won't be able to process the response as there is another structure.

I was trying to check if it's an error  with `echo ${json} | jq '. | select (.| has("error")) | has("error")'`, but this works only if it's an error response, if it's a "good" one - jq fails.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the responses are going to be of a specific type (an object vs an array), you could just test for that type.

```
$ <<<"$json" jq 'arrays'  # "good" response
$ <<<"$json" jq 'objects' # "bad" response
```

You could add additional checks as needed.

Comment: But, how do I check, if it returns nothing (no output) if there are no arrays/objects? I tried using `[[ $(<<<"$json" jq 'objects') = "" ]]`, but it doesn't seem to return any 'checkable' value...

Comment: So you literally just want to check if it's an object (is an error) or an array (it is not an error) if I'm not mistaken. But not do anything else with it? Then if that's the case then there's always just a simple type check as peak points out. `type == "object"`. jq is far more capable than doing just that... but you haven't specified what you're intending to do with these results.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I just need to list elements in the console if the response is okay, and if it's not, get an error message.
Anyways, I've already solved this with your answer and length check (error response is empty if processed with your "method").

Answer (score 0):

You should consider calling jq just once, along the lines:

```
 if type == "object" 
 then ...
 else ...
 end
```